# Google play services dont work

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I've done everything according to http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html , but libary is not even recognized. http://oi61.tinypic.com/hs80gz.jpg As you see object are in red, so they do not work, but there is no error. Tried clean, didn't work.

Here is te code of gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.r.ugani"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
}
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.r.ugani">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Ugani.Main" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Correct"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_correct"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Pass"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pass"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Results"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_results"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Instructions"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_instructions"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Ugani.Instructions" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Game"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Ugani.Game" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PreTimer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pre_timer"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you try putting `6.5.87` instead of `6.5.+`?

Comment: Yes, but with no success.

Comment: Have you checked your sha1 key and on the api console have you made sure the public and client keys are using the correct package name etc. Also if you havnt't agreed to the new terms on the api console that can cause issues. And obviously make sure you've enabled your api's

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment because i dont have 50 rep
Quick question, did you downloaded the necessary library to your project?

Comment: Yes I did. I did everything according to tutorial on developer.android